# parasite logging using Everyplay with OpenAL

Tags: openal, everyplay

I'm having trouble with Everyplay v1.4.2 used with OpenAL. The behaviour works fine but everytime a sound is playing, I get a log saying : "Everyplay OpenAL missing implementation: alGetSourcef 2401, AL_SEC_OFFSET, *value".

I have also tried deactivating OpenAL from this bit of code I found in Everyplay.h :

```
@interface EveryplayFeatures : NSObject
/*
 * To disable Everyplay OpenAL implementation, override this class
 * method to return NO.
 */
+ (BOOL) supportsOpenAL;

/*
 * CocosDenshion background music support currently lacks hardware
 * decoder support. To disable recording support for background music,
 * override this class method to return NO.
 */
+ (BOOL) supportsCocosDenshion;
@end
```

I'm not sure how to do what it says. I have tried creating a implementation of this interface in a file named "EveryplayFeatures.mm" :

```
@implementation EveryplayFeatures

+ (BOOL) supportsOpenAL
{
    return NO;
}

+ (BOOL) supportsCocosDenshion
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

This doesn't change a thing.

Does anyone know what the first error message means and how to fix it? Else how can I effectively disable the OpenAL support of Everyplay?

Comment: As of Everyplay SDK 1.6.2, querying AL_SEC_OFFSET through alGetSourcef is now supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Everyplay does not yet support AL_SEC_OFFSET which your audio code is using. To make the EveryplayFeatures work change it like this:

EveryplayFeatures.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EveryplayFeatures : NSObject

@end
```

EveryplayFeatures.m

```
@implementation EveryplayFeatures (Private)

+ (BOOL) supportsOpenAL {
    return NO;
}

+ (BOOL) supportsCocosDenshion {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: btw. you may leave the supportsCocosDenshion out since YES is the default value for it